# Event.aspx display page displays empty after refresh

Tags: calendar, events, modern

Has anyone else had a problem with {site}/_layouts/15/Event.aspx?ListGuid={guid}&ItemId={ItemId} not displaying the event info after it is refreshed? Whe I click on an event tile from the Events part on a modern page, I see the event info in Event.aspx, but when I refresh it does not display - only the header and left nav are visible.

I have the same problem if I try to enter that url directly.

Answer (score 0):

I have replicated the issue on 3 different SharePoint tenants and it seems like it's a bug. I have raised the same issue to Microsoft and I will update my answer once I hear back from them.

**Update**: It's indeed a bug. I received the following response from Microsoft.

> Hi Dhruv,
>
> I just wanted to follow up with you after our call with some of the
>   pertinent information we discussed on the phone!
>
> When refreshing an Event being viewed on a Communication site in
>   SharePoint, the page shows up blank. I was able to recreate this
>   issue, and a colleague was as well, so it is very likely a backend
>   bug.
>
> I am going to contact our systems administrator to see if there are
>   any escalations currently bringing this issue up to the engineers, and
>   will update you with what he finds!
>
> Regardless, I will try to run some backend diagnostics to try and
>   resolve the issue on both this tenant and my own.
>
> If there's anything you would like to add, please do so in a reply to
>   this email.
>
> Wishing you all the best, Jesse Office 365 Support